# How to add a prefix to a string if it ends with a particular character (Pandas) i.e. add '-' to string given it ends with '-'

Tags: python, pandas

For a particular column (dtype = object), how can I add '-' to the start of the string, given it ends with '-'.

i.e convert:  'MAY500-' to '-May500-'

(I need to add this to every element in the column)

Comment: you should consider using the mask solution. It is using boolean to add the `-` which is much faster than other solutions you have received in the answer section

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
def add_prefix(text):
    # If text is null or empty string the -1 index will result in IndexError
    if text and text[-1] == "-":
        return "-"+text
    return text

df = pd.DataFrame(data={'A':["MAY500", "MAY500-", "", None, np.nan]})
# Change the column to string dtype first
df['A'] = df['A'].astype(str)
df['A'] = df['A'].apply(add_prefix)

0      MAY500
1    -MAY500-
2            
3        None
4         nan
Name: A, dtype: object
```

Comment: Great!! Thanks so much!

Comment: `df['A'] = df['A'].apply(lambda x:"-"+x if x.str.endswith("-").any() else x, axis=1)`

Comment: @learning_to_code always avoid `.apply` when possible, it is not an optimal solution

Answer (score 3):

Try something like this:

```
#setup
df = pd.DataFrame({'col':['aaaa','bbbb-','cc-','dddddddd-']})

mask = df.col.str.endswith('-'), 'col'
df.loc[mask] = '-' + df.loc[mask]
```

**Output**

```
df
          col
0        aaaa
1      -bbbb-
2        -cc-
3  -dddddddd-
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `np.select`
Given a dataframe like this:

```
df
  values
0  abcd-
1  a-bcd
2   efg-
```

You can use `np.select` as follows:

```
df['values'] = np.select([df['values'].str.endswith('-')], ['-' + df['values']], df['values'])
```

output:

```
df
   values
0  -abcd-
1   a-bcd
2   -efg-
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a knack for using apply with lambda functions a lot. It just makes the code a lot easier to read.

```
df['value'] = df['value'].apply(lambda x: '-'+str(x) if str(x).endswith('-') else x)
```